# Macro to set print area from user input

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code that I am using right now.

```
Sub PrintArea()
Dim arange
    Rows = InputBox("How many Rows do you want to print (Between 1 and 48)?", "Row Selection")
.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(A, B, C).Rows
End Sub
```

When I try to run the macro I get "Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference" and it highlights the .Range in my code.

I want the print area to always be columns A-C, but the rows will vary between 2-48 depending on what I am printing.

Edit: Stepping through the code, it stops at this line,

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(A:C, "arange")
```

and gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Stepping through the code, it stops at this line, ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(A:C, "arange") and gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetMyPrintArea()
    Dim UserInput As Variant

    Do
        UserInput = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many Rows do you want to print (Between 1 and 48)?", Title:="Row Selection", Type:=1)
        If VarType(UserInput) = vbBoolean And UserInput = False Then Exit Sub
        DoEvents
    Loop While UserInput < 2 Or UserInput > 48

    Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:C" & UserInput
End Sub
```

- Note that the `Do … Loop While UserInput < 2 Or UserInput > 48` forces the input box to appear again until the user put in a value between 2 … 48.
- This `If VarType(UserInput) = vbBoolean And UserInput = False Then Exit Sub` is to check if the user pressed the cancel button and then to abort.
- Don't name your procedure `PrintArea` because this is already used by Excel `PageSetup.PrintArea` and can easily confuse.

Comment: Whoo it works now! Out of curiosity, what's the difference between InputBox and Application.InputBox? is InputBox an outdated method?

Comment: `Application.InputBox` provides the parameter `Type` where you can force it to accept numbers only `Type:=1` while `InputBox` has no `Type` parameter. See [Application.InputBox Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.InputBox) • But note that even if forced to numbers it returns a boolean if cancel is pressed. Therefore you need to declare `Dim UserInput As Variant`